# Nginx vhost prestashop on sub url

Tags: php, nginx, prestashop-1.6, vhosts

I have 2 projects on same domain -- domain.ltd

On direct domain, i have a symfony project -- this part is OK.
But for my sake, i try to let the old prestashop site on sub url, like domain.ltd/old

So my vhost is :

```
# Redirect all HTTP traffic
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name www.domain.ltd domain.ltd;
    root /home/user/projects/old.domain.ltd/; 
    location = /{
        # On redirige toutes les requêtes vers HTTPS
        rewrite ^ https://www.domain.ltd$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location /old {
        root /home/user/projects/old.domain.ltd/;

        index index.php;

        rewrite ^/old/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/old/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        error_page 404 /old/index.php?controller=404;       

        location ~ ^/old/\.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            root /home/user/projects/old.domain.ltd/;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-user.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.ltd.old.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.ltd.old.error.log;
    }



    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.ltd.old.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.ltd.old.error.log;
}

# HTTPS request on symfony
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.domain.ltd;
    # this part works fine with my symfony project
}
```

I don't understand why my config is not working. When i go on back-office page, my web browser download the file of index.php.

If anyone have an idea ??